# Adding multiple events to onPress function in React Native

Tags: button, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

When I press the button, it supposed to navigate to another page and it also increase the view count.

But I can't figure out anyway to implement them at the same time.

This is my code:

```
<Button onPress={Actions.ideaOnClick}>
<Button onPress={() => this.setState({views: ++this.state.views})}>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
yourFunction(){
 Actions.ideaOnClick();
 this.setState({views: ++this.state.views});
}

<Button onPress={this.yourFunction.bind(this)}}>
```

Answer (score 19):

Just create a function that does both things. No other way around it (if a lib has a utillity for that it would do something similar) since `onPress` is a single function.

```
<Button onPress={() => {
    Actions.ideaOnClick()
    this.setState({views: ++this.state.views})
}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const function  = () => {
functionToBeExecuted();
IncreaseViewCount();
}

return(
   <Button onPress={function} /> 
)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.